# view object data is not showing at the first page loading, it is showing at the second load

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, pageload

I am have two `JSF` pages `index.jsf` and `detalis.jsf` . In the `index.jsf` I am showing a list of links in `ADF table` that's mapped to some `view object`. Each link represent the **Title** attribute in the row. When the user click the link I am getting the value of the key attribute and store it in the `session`.

After that the `detalis.jsf` should show details information for the row the user selected in the `index.jsf`. I am achieving that by executing query on the same `view object` based on the key value coming from the `session`, this query execution is tacking place in the `OnPageLoad()` since I am using `PagePhaseListener`.

**Problem** is when the user click some link in the `index.jsf` the `detalis.jsf` is appearing with no data at the **first time**. But if I go back to `index.jsf`  and press the same link again `detalis.jsf` is showing the right data.

***So, the work flow is working at the second try not at the first one.***

```
I am using Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3 with ADF Technology
```

Comment: Same here. Have you found a solution to this ?

Comment: I found a workaround solution. This not the straight solution put it works for me. The trick is to have a variable in the session which indicate if the page is calling for the first time and based on this value I am recalling the method that load the view object. Steps as follow: 1- on search.jsf I am setting the session variable to 0. 2- in the detalis.jsf I am getting the variable form the session. 3- If it is 0 then I recall the load method again and change the session variable to 1. This is the trick